# Can a truck driving company (USA) use an outward facing camera as an inward facing (in-cab) camera without driver's consent/knowledge?

Tags: united-states, privacy, employment

Trucking company has outward facing cameras which drivers are aware of. However, no official company (written) policy was provided about the outward facing cameras recordings, usage, or storage. Now? Can the trucking company use the outward facing camera as a justification to install driver facing camera? For example, can the company use reflections off the windshield from the outward facing camera to accuse the driver of misconduct or violation of company policy? The reflection does not have a direct view of the driver or inside the cab. Therefore, no face is available on the outward facing dash cam. Yet, the company is trying to use the outward facing camera as a justification for a driver facing camera. I'm assuming they can? As I have been told over and over, "it's the company's truck and they can install whatever they see fit for safety purposes." However, does the driver have any rights if they are being recorded indirectly without his/her knowledge? These drivers have a clean driving record with no accidents or tickets. No written policy is in the handbook addressing cameras or camera use.